# Visual SVN Specify URL with new port

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, svn, version-control, visualsvn

Our SVN server was initially setup to run on port 443, we had to change it to run on port 8443 because it was causing conflicts with IIS.

My question is how do I change the repository URL of all my projects to point to the new address?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

select your projects folder click realocate in the subversion menu and add the new address